# Bash version does not support option local -n

Tags: bash, function, version, local

I have a function and I us local -n, in certain laptop this option works but another laptop does not supported this option because of bash version

```
sorted_d() {

  local -n _less_d=$1
  local -n _more_d=$2
  sorted_by=false
  IFS=$'\n'

  if $sorted_by
  then
    less_d_sorted=($(for each in ${_less_d[@]}; do echo $each; done | sort -k2 -n))
    more_d_sorted=($(for each in ${_more_d[@]}; do echo $each; done | sort -k2 -n))

  fi

}

arr={1 2 3 4 5}
sorted_d arr
```

How use function without local -n

Comment: Does `declare` accept the `-n` and `-l`?

Comment: Where do you ever change the value of `sorted_by`? Right now, you could just drop those two lines, because your `if` statement never executes its body.

Answer (score 3):

`_less_d` and `_more_d` are being used as local aliases for a pair of global arrays whose names are passed as arguments. You should be able to use indirect parameter expansion here.

```
sorted_d() {

  local _less_d=$1
  local _more_d=$2
  sorted_by=false
  IFS=$'\n'

  if $sorted_by
  then
    tmp="$_less_d[@]"
    less_d_sorted=($(for each in "${!tmp}"; do echo $each; done | sort -k2 -n))
    tmp="$_more_d[@]"
    more_d_sorted=($(for each in "${!tmp}"; do echo $each; done | sort -k2 -n))

  fi

}
```

Comment: indirect variables are way messier than that: `local _less_d=$1; local tmp="${_less_d}[@]"; local less_d_values=( "${!tmp}" )` will get you a copy of the values of the array names passed to the function. The intermediate `tmp` string is required, the `${!var}` indirect syntax doesn't work with array subscripts, the "bang" syntax for arrays gets you the array indices.

Comment: Ah, right, I confused `!` with `#`, which can stack on (select) other expansions.